# How do I use JSON and return data with D3

Tags: javascript, json, api, d3.js

I am currently playing with learning D3 JS and am trying to make a bar chart from the live information I am pulling from the openweather API. I am trying to get the City Name and its respective temperature at the time of the query.

While trying to set up my chart, I keep running into the problem of being unable to return a number value for each bars height and width as I get NaN for each value. Currently, what I have is a function that iterates through the data and creates an object with the temperature and name of the city. I then push them into an array, weather, which I am calling for my data.

Can somebody explain or figure out why I am getting NaN and how I might be able to pull specifically the data's temperature value?

```
var weather =[];
var name;

var margin = {
top: 50,
right:30,
bottom:40,
left:50
}

var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom ,
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
barwidth = 50,
barOffset = 5;

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(weather)])
    .range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(0, weather.length))
    .rangeBands([0, width], .2)

var tempColor;

//Load external data//
d3.json("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=192710,2643743,1850147,2988507,524901,5368361,1816670,2177052,1835847,3128760,7533612,292223,7870410,3451190,1275339,4904381,5856195,&units=metric", function(data){

var list = data.list

for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    var country = list[i]
    var nameOfCountry = list[i].name
    var temperature = +country.main.temp
    var countryWeather = [ nameOfCountry, temperature ]

    weather.push({ "temperature":temperature, "nameOfCountry":nameOfCountry})
}
console.log(weather)

// Horizontal Color Gradient for bars
var colors = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, weather.length*.33, weather.length*.66, weather.length])
    .range(['#FFB832','#C61C6F','#268BD2','#85992C'])


//Create the canvas//
var Canvas = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
.style('background','#FFF')
.attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform','translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .style('background', '#C9D7D6')
        .selectAll('rect').data(weather)
        .enter().append('rect')
            .style('fill', function(d,i){
                return colors(i);
            })
        .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr('height', 0)
            .attr('x',function(d,i){
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr('y', height)
            .on('mouseover', function(d){

                tooltip.transition()
                    .style('opacity', .9)

                tooltip.html(d)
                    .style('left',(d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
                    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 35) + 'px')

                tempColor = this.style.fill;
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition().delay(500).duration(800)
                    .style('opacity', .5)
                    .style('fill', 'yellow')
            })
            .on('mouseout',function(d){
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition().delay(500).duration(800)
                    .style('opacity',1)
                    .style('fill', tempColor)
            })

Canvas.transition()
.attr('height',function(d){
    return yScale(d);
})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d);
})
.delay(function(d,i){
    return i * 20;
})
.duration(800)
.ease('elastic')

var vGuideScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(weather)])
.range([height,0])

var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(vGuideScale)
.orient('left')
.ticks(10)

var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)
vGuide.attr('transform','translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top +')')
vGuide.selectAll('path')
    .style({
        fill:'none',
        stroke: '#000'
    })
vGuide.selectAll('line')
    .style({
        stroke: '#000'
    })

var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xScale)
.orient('bottom')
.tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d,i){
    return !(i % (weather.length/5)) 
}))

var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)
hGuide.attr('transform','translate(' + (margin.left-6) + ',' + (height + margin.top) +')')
hGuide.selectAll('path')
    .style({
        fill:'none',
        stroke: "#000"
    })
hGuide.selectAll('line')
    .style({
        stroke:"#000"
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you point to where specifically in the code the variable is `NaN` when you are not expecting it to be?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I am reading console errors after I serve the code on a python server into my browser.

Comment: Currently my array of 17 objects looks like this:  var weather = [ {nameOfCountry: "Kiambu", temperature: 14.64},etc...]

Comment: The problem is occurring in the `Canvas.transition()` call. Perhaps you meant something like `Canvas.selectAll('rect').transition()`? Regardless, it doesn't look like your rects are being created properly anyway.

Comment: The transition method and the selectAll method both append attributes for width and height in relation to the xScale and yScale gathered from d, the data. However, because the values returned for them are currently NaN, I have a feeling that they are taking strings, perhaps the names or unable to get the temperature data in particular.

Comment: The exact error I am getting is  'Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN" ' and ' Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN" '

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your domain is not set correctly

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    //.domain([0, d3.max(weather)]) Remove this line
    .range([0, height]);
```

Remove that line and insert it after `weather` has been populated. Use the [d3.extent()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays) method to get both the min and max of `weather.temperature` simultaneously

```
for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    var country = list[i]
    var nameOfCountry = list[i].name
    var temperature = +country.main.temp
    var countryWeather = [ nameOfCountry, temperature ]

    weather.push({ "temperature":temperature, "nameOfCountry":nameOfCountry})
}
yScale.domain(d3.extent(weather, function(d) { return d.temperature; }));
console.log(weather)
```

Also remember you need to access the temperature attribute specifically

```
Canvas.transition()
.attr('height',function(d){
    return yScale(d.temperature);
})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d.temperature);
})
```

Comment: Cool this solves my query. However now I also have problems distributing the bars and their width evenly along the xScale. All my bars currently have a default width of 2080 pixels. How do I set up the width of all of the bars to evenly distribute on the xScale and then also distribute their x position according to their index?

Comment: @user3208676 All you have to do is move your `xScale.domain` line after the for loop, like you did with the `yScale`.

Comment: @user3208676 I hope this answer helped. If you think this is the best answer to your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark above